# Epel Repo is installed but desired packagesnot found

Tags: centos, software-installation, repository

I have got epel repo and installed it. It shows "package epel-release-6-8.noarch is already installed" when I want to ensure that it has been installed.

```
[root@static ~]# rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    package epel-release-6-8.noarch is already installed
```

But I cannot install some packages that are placed in this repository like unrar rar aria2c

```
[root@static ~]# yum install rar unrar
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.antilo.de
 * epel: mirror.wiuwiu.de
 * extras: mirror.ratiokontakt.de
 * updates: mirror.ratiokontakt.de
No package rar available.
No package unrar available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

What should I do?
It is centos6.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages you are looking for aren’t [available in EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#What_packages_and_versions_are_available_in_EPEL.3F) (check the list of packages [starting with ‘a’](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/fedora/epel/6/x86_64/Packages/a/), [‘r’](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/fedora/epel/6/x86_64/Packages/r/) and [‘u’](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/fedora/epel/6/x86_64/Packages/u/)). `unrar`’s license is [inappropriate for EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Licensing:Unrar), as is RAR’s; `aria2` is fine but isn’t part of [EPEL 6](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/aria2/overview/).

Comment: So how could I install them. All docs say install from rpmforge-release and rpmforge has been replaced by epel.

Comment: I don’t know where you’d get them for CentOS, apart from building from source.

Answer (score 0):

Found it in this repo by negativo17.org, this worked for me:

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-rar.repo https://negativo17.org/repos/epel-rar.repo
sudo yum update
sudo yum install rar
```